# Entity Framework 6 DB first with multiple data models for huge Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an MSSQL DB with more than 1000 tables, and I wanted to use EF 6 in my project as DB is large and already running with another system so I will go with DB first approach.

1. My question is that what is the best practice to use multiple EF data models(each will contain 10 or less tables) will communicate with each other as it will be in different context (e.g. getting data from product table in sales model).
2. How to manage same Tables in different models e.g. users table probably will be in each model.
3. Is there anyway that I can use for updating all models at once or is there any post-build option to automate updating all models from db and what will be the affect on customized tables.

Already done: Created multiple data models in the same project with the same DB in different folders(working fine).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all of your questions is Domain Driven Design.
Go through Julie Lerman's [DDD Bounded Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx). She has explained everything in an obvious and comprehensive way.

For data sharing she has another article. Have a look at [this too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802601.aspx)